# Scared of my dog's behavior - is it anxiety or some superstition stuff?

Tags: dogs, behavior, breeding, vocalizations, anxiety

I have a problem with my 8 (soon 9) year old Labrador. At night, he runs away and always comes back really tired, but keeps going outside every night. From time to time, he howls outside the house (alone). He is never hungry, thirsty, has a lots of space around the house, but keeps doing this. I'm not really superstitious, but this really creeps me off.

Why does he run away and howl outside?

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking, are you concerned that he howls outside?

Comment: Yes,and why is he running away? He started doing this like 10 days ago every night :(

Comment: Is your Labrador desexed?

Comment: No.You think it could be something related to hormones? That crossed my mind too

Comment: there could be a bitch in heat somewhere.

Comment: Could be,but in this time of the year it's strange

Comment: Your house is no longer safe to live in. Especially in night time, the spirits come out. Dogs have a sixth sense, so they run being afraid. Really smart thing would be to change the house.

Comment: Hahah please don't creep me off even more.I know dogs have sixth sense and that creeps me even more.Our neighbour died days ago but i don't want to connect that to my dog :(

Answer (score 3):

Since your dog is not fixed, I think it is likely that there is a female dog on heat close by. There isn't really a specific season for dogs as it is based on their age.

If you feel up to it maybe try following him or put a tracking device on his collar. The alternative is to try make sure he can't get out. The world is a dangerous place for dogs and he might get hit by a car or become injured in another way.

Comment: We finally managed to block him way out.I'm glad he's ok.He seems ok now,days ago he could barely walk.Thank you for an answer!

Comment: That's great! Hopefully it doesn't happen again!